# How can i buildi multiple VisualWebparts using VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-web-part

Can i create/build multiple Visual webparts in Visual Studio 2010?
    If yes i do i set up  the strcuture?
`Will it have seprate feature or does it come under 1 feature?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple Visual webparts in same VS.NET Project (choose Add New Item). You can add them in single FEATURE using Feature designer.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple webparts can be added to project.

1.Start Visual Studio 2010.

2.On the File menu, click New, and then click Project.

3.In the Installed Templates section, expand either Visual Basic or C#, expand SharePoint, and then click 2010.

4.In the template pane, click Visual Web Part.

To add webparts again right click on the project and choose ADD new Item